# ValueError: Could not process parameters Python MYSQL Connector

Tags: python, mysql

No clue what I'm missing here. This is my first time writing a Python SQL script. I've kept it pretty simple to start on purpose.

```
import mysql.connector

MINI = mysql.connector.connect(
        host="localhost",
        user="root",
        password="password",
        database="mini"
    )

MINI_CURSOR = MINI.cursor()

def main():
    print("Welcome to Mini Memoir!")
    print("Add a memory for a little in your life.")
    print("Look back on these precious moments at anytime!")
    get_caregiver()

def get_caregiver():
    add_caregiver = "INSERT INTO entries (first_name) VALUES (%s)"
    first_name = ("Isabella")
    MINI_CURSOR.execute(add_caregiver, first_name)
    MINI.commit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: What's the error? Could you provide de error log?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the MySQL documentation:

```py
cursor.execute(operation, params=None, multi=False)
iterator = cursor.execute(operation, params=None, multi=True)
```

Where params is a tuple

> This method executes the given database operation (query or command).
> The parameters found in the tuple or dictionary params are bound to
> the variables in the operation. Specify variables using %s or %(name)s
> parameter style (that is, using format or pyformat style). execute()
> returns an iterator if multi is True. Note
>
> In Python, a tuple containing a single value must include a comma. For
> example, ('abc') is evaluated as a scalar while ('abc',) is evaluated
> as a tuple.

```py
def get_caregiver():
    add_caregiver = "INSERT INTO entries (first_name) VALUES (%s)"
    first_name = ("Isabella",)
    MINI_CURSOR.execute(add_caregiver, first_name)
    MINI.commit()
```

Look at first_name variable, is a tuple of one element, you need to define it with a comma at the end. `("Isabella",)`

Answer (score 1):

the connector expect array or tuples

in case of a tuple your code looks like(see the tow dimensions are needed even for only one variaböe

```
def get_caregiver():
    add_caregiver = "INSERT INTO entries (first_name) VALUES (%s)"
    first_name = ("Isabella")
    MINI_CURSOR.execute(add_caregiver, (first_name,))
    MINI.commit()
```

Comment: I was reading this article https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-mysql-insert-into-table/

Comment: This worked I was running the wrong version of my code and not the updated one. I'm annoyed the article didn't show the tuple formation.